# How to display a input button and close the current window

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a call to a service using ajax, i would like if everything goes well on the ajax call to enable or display an input (maybe in a div?) on my page that when clicked it will close the current window. What is the best way to do this using javascript?

Here is my function of a javascript class:

```
MyFunction.prototype.init = function(param1, param2) {

    this.MyParams = new Hash();
    this.MyParams.set("param1", param1);
    this.MyParams.set("param2", param2);

    new Ajax.Request('MyService.asmx/MyServiceFunction', {
        method: 'post',
        onSuccess: //how can i do what i mentioned here?,
        onFailure: failureFunc,
        onException: ajaxError,
        parameters: this.MyParams
    });
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `onSuccess` part you have to put something like this:

```
OnSuccess: function() {
   $('div_to_show').show();
}
```

In the HTML part you will have this:

```
<div id="div_to_show">
   <input type="button" name="close" id="close" value="close" onclick="javascript:window.close();" />
</div>
```

Of course you have to hide the div on document loading.

Comment: Great, I am sorry not too good with javascript related things. How can I do this on the load?, can I do it on the server side? like..  in c# add a runat=server then do div_to_show.visible = false; ?

Comment: Using prototype you can do it by this way:

`document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  $('#div_to_show').invoke('hide');
});`

Or:

`document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  $('#div_to_show').hide();
});`

I'm not good with Prototype JS Framework.